# NoClassDefinitionFoundError foundjavax/transaction/TransactionManager

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Hi everyone I am getting problem while I am trying to integrate spring 3.0 with hibernate 3.1, why I am getting this type of error. In "HibernateDAO" class I just used "autowired" technique for "HibernateTemplate" and its throwing error...
I am enclosing "applicationcontext" and "web.xml"

```
 applicationContext:@

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <beans 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation=
   "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd" > 

   <!--<context:annotation-config />-->

   <mvc:annotation-driven/>
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring" />

      <bean              class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"      value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView"/>
    <property name="prefix"  value="/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>


   <bean id="bs" class="com.spring.BookServiceImpl"  />

    <bean id="hbdao" class="com.spring.HibernateBookDAO"  />

    <bean id="htemp" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate"  autowire="constructor" />

    <!--<bean id="txManger"     class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.TransactionManager" autowire="byName" />-->

    <!--<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate.Hibernate TransactionManager">
   <property name="sessionFactory">
    <ref bean="sessionFactory"/>
   </property>
  </bean>
     -->

   <bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
    <map>
    <entry key="hibernate.dialect"    value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
    <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
    </map>
    </property>

    <property name="mappingResources">
    <list>
    <value>com/spring/book.hbm.xml</value>
    </list>
    </property>

    </bean>


 <bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName"
        value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver">
    </property>
    <property name="url"
        value="jdbc:mysql://loacalhost:3306/napiertest">
    </property>
    <property name="username" value="root"></property>
    <property name="password" value="napier"></property>
    </bean>

    </beans>
```

web.xml :@

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app version="3.0" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
 <display-name></display-name>  
 <welcome-file-list>
 <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>

 <servlet>
 <servlet-name>applicationContext</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-  class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
     </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>applicationContext</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
       </servlet-mapping>

      </web-app>
```

Comment: Why in hell are you starting a new project with spring and hibernate versions that are obsolete for years?

Comment: It clearly says the class is not found, check whether the jar file is present in the build path and is having permissions to load during the application startup.

Comment: why are you *.do(struts) extension in spring. Are you want to build a spring mvc application?

Comment: yes i am trying to build spring mvc project

Comment: I know that somewhere few jars is missing from classpath. but i dont know which one it is.. i am giving you the list of jars

aopalliance
aspectjweaver
cglib-nodep-2.1_3
commons-logging-1.0.4
hibernate-3.1
JDBC Driver
jstl-1.2
log4j-1.2.9
mysql
ojdbc6

Comment: org.springframework.aop-3.0.5.RELEASE
org.springframework.asm-3.0.5.RELEASE
org.springframework.aspects-3.0.5.RELEASE
org.springframework.beans-3.0.5.RELEASE
org.springframework.context.support-3.0.5.RELEASE
org.springframework.context-3.0.5.RELEASE
org.springframework.core-3.0.5.RELEASE
org.springframework.expression-3.0.5.RELEASE
org.springframework.instrument.tomcat-3.0.5.RELEASE
org.springframework.instrument-3.0.5.RELEASE
org.springframework.jdbc-3.0.5.RELEASE
org.springframework.jms-3.0.5.RELEASE
org.springframework.orm-3.0.5.RELEASE

Comment: org.springframework.oxm-3.0.5.RELEASE
org.springframework.spring-library-3.0.5.RELEASE
org.springframework.test-3.0.5.RELEASE
org.springframework.transaction-3.0.5.RELEASE
org.springframework.web.portlet-3.0.5.RELEASE
org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.5.RELEASE
org.springframework.web.struts-3.0.5.RELEASE
org.springframework.web-3.0.5.RELEASE

aopalliance
aspectjweaver
cglib-nodep-2.1_3
commons-logging-1.0.4
hibernate-3.1
JDBC Driver
jstl-1.2
log4j-1.2.9
mysql
ojdbc6

Comment: I know its out of date. But now i can reach step by step on spring 4.0 so I will use later. I am doing it just for keep in touch. I am working in JAVA env but my company is using there own framework for the web app

Comment: Please don't add code, lists etc. as comments. Edit your initial question and extend it with the desired information. That way it remains readable.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, Your applicationContext Dispatcher servlet having *.do extension.

```
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>applicationContext</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Change your controller like this.. Your RequestMapping should have .do extension. Requests are coming from web.xml with .do extension, the requests should match with your controller @RequestMapping annotation. So add like this,

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class AppController {

@RequestMapping(value="/home.do" method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String SampleMethod(Model model){
```

Comment: this is my index.jsp :@ its forwarding control to home.do
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="3;url=home.do">
</head>
<body>

<h1> <font color="Blue" >please wait.... </font></h1>
  <h3>     while Page is loading              </h3>
 </body>
</html>

Comment: Then follow the request mapping what i have mentioned above the post. That will work for your case.

Comment: i have done like what did you say but i am still getting below exp.
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateBookDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate com.spring.dao.HibernateBookDAO.htemp; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/TransactionManager

and i have added two more jar javaee.jar and jta.jar suggested on google

Comment: Use @ Repository anntoation top of your hibernateBookDAO. And make sure that use @ Service annotation in your Business Logic.

Comment: The error clearly states a missing dependency (the JTA jars) this won't provide an answer. Also doing a mapping of `*.do` will also match on a controller using `/whatever` as that is enabled by default and a mapping of `/whatever.*` is also added. (Enable debug logging and check your logs).